# JScrollPane does not scroll when I paint the JPanel in its ViewPort

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to draw some tree structures on a `JPanel` subclass that is the client (the ViewPort view) of a `JScrollPane`. I can draw the tree just fine, but even though it is larger than the viewport, the `JScrollPane` doesn't scroll. An identical `JScrollPane` whose client is a `JTextArea` works fine.

The code below creates a Frame with the 2 scroll panes side by side -- one works and the other doesn't. (I am just drawing text for simplicity.) I am a novice with Swing GUIs, so I am undoubtedly doing something stupid, but days of searching and reading have not shown me my error.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class ScrollTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ScrollTest() {
        initComponents();
        prepComponents();
    }

    void prepComponents() {
        leftScrollPaneContent = new JTextArea();
        leftScrollPane.setViewportView(leftScrollPaneContent);
        rightScrollPaneContent = new TestPanel();
        rightScrollPane.setViewportView(rightScrollPaneContent);
        String s = "Test of JTextArea setText()\n\n";
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            s += "Line " + i + ": This is a test.\n";
        }
        leftScrollPaneContent.setText(s);
        rightScrollPaneContent.repaint();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        leftPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanelLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        leftScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        rightPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        subclassLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        rightScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanelLabel.setText("JTextArea in a ScrollPane");

        leftScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        leftScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout leftPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(leftPanel);
        leftPanel.setLayout(leftPanelLayout);
        leftPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                leftPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(leftPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(leftScrollPane)
                        .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(leftPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                        .addComponent(jPanelLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        leftPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                leftPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(leftPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanelLabel)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(leftScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
        );

        subclassLabel.setText("JPanel subclass in a ScrollPane");

        rightScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        rightScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout rightPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(rightPanel);
        rightPanel.setLayout(rightPanelLayout);
        rightPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                rightPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(rightPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(rightScrollPane)
                        .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(rightPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(66, 66, 66)
                        .addComponent(subclassLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        rightPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                rightPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(rightPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(subclassLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(rightScrollPane)
                        .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(leftPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(rightPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addComponent(leftPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                                        .addComponent(rightPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScrollTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel jPanelLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel leftPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane leftScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JPanel rightPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane rightScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JLabel subclassLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private JTextArea leftScrollPaneContent;
    private JPanel rightScrollPaneContent;

    public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawString("Test of JPanel g.drawString()\n", 10, 20);
            for (int i = 3; i < 33; i++) {
                g.drawString("Line " + (i-2) + ": This is a test.", 10, 20 * i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JTextArea leftScrollPaneContent` overrides
`getPreferredSize()` which returns a size cleverly
derived from the actual text and font.
The surrounding `JScrollPane` uses this size to decide
if scroll-bars are needed.
Furthermore, `JTextArea` (because extending from `JTextComponent`)
also implements the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface.
This gives some additional hints to the surrounding `JScollPane`
for a better scrolling behavior.

---

Your `TestPanel rightScrollPaneContent` does nothing of that.
Therefore it inherits a `getPreferredSize()` method from `JPanel`
returning just a tiny 10x10 size (which would make sense for an
empty `JPanel` with no child components).
Therefore the surrounding `JScrollPane` decides there is no
need to show any scroll-bars for this allegedly tiny content.

Hence, most importantly, in your `TestPanel` you need to override
`getPreferredSize()` and return a reasonable large size there.
As a bonus (for better scrolling behavior) you may also implement
the `Scrollable` interface.
Or you choose to extend your class from another class
which already implements the `Scrollable` interface.

Comment: Those were the insights I needed -- thank you, Thomas.  I implemented the Scrollable interface (pretty easy) and overrode the getPreferredSize method. Problem solved!